# Swift: Calling function from a different target

Tags: ios, swift, access-levels, ios-targets

I have two targets (`Target A`, `Target B`) and from `Target B` I would like to call a function which is located in `Target A`. I get the `Use of Unresolved Identifier` error when trying to compile as expected since `ClassA.swift` isn't part of `Target B`. So I tried to set the Target membership of `ClassA.swift` to include `Target B` as well but the issue with this is that `ClassA.swift` touches so many files and also imports different modules. It wouldn't make sense to include everything else in `Target B`. I also tried to set the `ClassA` as `open` by declaring it as such but that doesn't do anything (maybe I'm doing something wrong there). Not really sure what else I can try to call the function in `Target A` from `Target B`

Target A > ClassA.swift > staticFunctionA()

Target B > ClassB.swift (calls staticFunctionA())

`ClassA.swift` has a few functions and those functions touch a number of files. This file is a wrapper file for a lot of other things that is does.  Of course if I make this file as part of `Target B`, I'll have to make other files part of `Target B` as well.

Comment: Extract out the function into a separate file, and include only that file in `Target A`. Additionally, the fact that your `ClassA.swift` "touches so many files" is probably a code smell, indicating that your class does too much, and needs to be broken down into smaller pieces.

Comment: Sounds like you should look into creating a Dynamic Framework that you can move ClassA and its dependencies into. That way, you can add the framework as a dependency for both TargetA and TargetB and both can access ClassA.

Comment: @Alexander I just updated my question in regards to `ClassA.swift` and it's functionality. It touches too many files because it's the main wrapper that has affects about 10 other files which I don't believe makes sense to move to `Target B`. Separating the function into a different file (which I have already done) does nothing as it's a wrapper function.

Comment: @AdamPro13 great thought, currently I am trying to look for a technique which would require less effort. If I can't find a solution, I will surely take the approach you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

To share the code in different targets, select ClassA.swift then check target which you would like to share ClassA.swift at "Target Membership" section

Comment: The issue with this is that I would need to change Target Membership of all the files that have functions that are called from `ClassA.swift`. I also have a ton of libraries that are being used across all these files. I mentioned this in my question.

Comment: @BhavikPatel Yes you are correct, Did you get any solution to this ?